# Function result-document() leaves file open

Tags: java, xml, xslt, xslt-2.0, saxon

I have a simple question:

I have and XSLT 2.0 transformation using SAXON.
As a part of this tranformation some information is written to a file using the `xsl:result-document` function.

After the transformation is completed, this result file is copied to another directory and then should be deleted, but that is not always successful.

My associates from across the Atlantic are respobnsible for the copy / delete mechanizm and are convinced that the XSLT transforamtion (that I provide) leave the result file open / locked so it can't be deleted.

I for one think that they somehow fail to close the file after it is copied.

That being said, this raises an obvious question for me:

**Question:**

Is it possible that this function creates the file but leaves it open / locked after the transformation? I was unable to find any relevant information on the internet.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Please ask Saxon-specific questions on the Saxon forums at saxonica.plan.io in preference. If you ask there then we have a process to make sure questions are answered; if you ask here, it is hit-and-miss. Which Saxon version are you using?

Comment: I'm using Saxon-PE 9.

Comment: 9 point what? There's a five-year difference between 9.0 and 9.5!

Answer (score 0):

I think [Saxon XSLT Transformation: How to close outputstream when failing during transformation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17998881/saxon-xslt-transformation-how-to-close-outputstream-when-failing-during-transfo?rq=1) suggests that a file might not be properly closed if a dynamic error occurs during the XSLT transformation. There is also the suggestion "You could work around the problem by registering your own OutputURIResolver (perhaps based on the standard one) which keeps track of all open output streams and has the ability to be called directly by the application to close them at the end." to work around the problem.

Comment: Interesting indeed, however if there are no errors the file should be closed yes?

Comment: As far as I know, yes, but you might want to wait for an answer by Michael Kay here or you could ask with detailed description on how you use Saxon on the Saxon forum.