# Why are only SOME of the files and folders not deleted?

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, stream, tomcat6

I am generating some files from my servlet (`output.txt`) and from an XSL file (the folder `generatedApps` and its content) and then pack the files and folders generated by the XSL transformation into a ZIP archive. After the client downloads the ZIP archive I want to delete it, as well as the other files and folders.

This is my code:

```
InputStream inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(request.getParameter("content")
        .getBytes("UTF-8"));
    try {
        TransformerFactory tFactory = new net.sf.saxon.TransformerFactoryImpl();
        Transformer transformer = tFactory.newTransformer(new StreamSource(
            getServletContext().getResourceAsStream("lib/GenerateGeddyJsCode.xsl")));
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("output.txt");
        transformer.transform(new StreamSource(inputStream), new StreamResult(fos));

        String appName = new Scanner(new File("output.txt")).useDelimiter("\\Z").next();

        ZipUsingJavaUtil zipper = new ZipUsingJavaUtil();
        zipper.zipFiles("generatedApps/" + appName, "generatedApps/" + appName + "Archive.zip");

        String path = "generatedApps/";
        String fileName = appName + "Archive.zip";
  File f = new File(path + fileName);       

  response.setContentType("application/zip");     
  response.setContentLength((int)f.length());  
  response.addHeader("Content-Disposition","attachment;filename=\"" + fileName + "\"");    
  byte[] arBytes = new byte[32768];     
  FileInputStream is = new FileInputStream(f);
  ServletOutputStream op = response.getOutputStream();     
  int count;
  while ((count = is.read(arBytes)) > 0)
  {
      op.write(arBytes, 0, count);     
  }
  op.flush();
  op.close();
  is.close();
  fos.close();
  inputStream.close();

  File toBeDel = new File("generatedApps/");
  GenerateGeddyJsCode.removeDirectory(toBeDel);

  File output = new File("output.txt");
  output.delete();
```

The method `removeDirectory` is the following:

```
public static void removeDirectory(File dir) {
    if (dir.isDirectory()) {
        File[] files = dir.listFiles();
        if (files != null && files.length > 0) {
            for (File aFile : files) {
                removeDirectory(aFile);
            }
        }   
    } else {
        dir.delete();
    }
}
```

The problem is that in the end only the ZIP archive is deleted (btw, the archive is inside `generatedApps`). I tried to close all the streams, because I've read that not closed streams prevent deletion.

How can I also delete the remaining files and folders?

**==================================== EDIT ========================================**

My updated deletion method:

```
public static void removeDirectory(File dir) {
if (dir.isDirectory()) {
    File[] files = dir.listFiles();
    if (files != null && files.length > 0) {
        for (File aFile : files) {
            removeDirectory(aFile);
        }
    } else if (files.length == 0) {
        dir.delete();
    }

} 
dir.delete();

}
```

Still not working.

**==================================== EDIT 2========================================**
Added:

```
InputStream inStream = getServletContext().getResourceAsStream("lib/GenerateGeddyJsCode.xsl");
StreamSource inStreamSource = new StreamSource(inStream);
Transformer transformer = tFactory.newTransformer(inStreamSource);
```

and later `inStream.close()`. Still not working.

Comment: in your code you never remove directories...

Comment: the problem is that it doesn't even delete my files from inside the folders

Comment: start by adding a delete() in case the folder is empty, correct your code in the question and then we go on... :)
Also, check if delete() returns 'true'

Comment: You need not use files, ZipOutputStream on the response.getOutputStream, as the XSLT result.

Comment: did an update... still nothing

Comment: Try removing the / from the end of the filepath. Just a hunch.

Comment: it is weird that it deletes the archive `generatedApps/MyAppArchive.zip`, but it doesn't delete the files from `generatedApps/MyApp/controller`...

Comment: Try printing the names of each file/directory instead of deleting them. This should help you troubleshoot.

Comment: I've already done that... it goes through each of them... but it only deletes the archive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check whether the Zip utility is closing the files properly...
Do you have access to the ZipUsingJavaUtil class source?

- Each entry in a zip file has to be closed.
- Every file input stream opened for the zip writing process should be
  closed.

Check the below sample:
http://www.journaldev.com/957/java-zip-example-to-zip-single-file-and-a-directory-recursively

Comment: I was so concentrated on the code I presented above that I didn't look in the zipper class... Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You never remove the directory in your removeDirectory method.

You need to remove the else to have it execute unconditionally (for directories as well as non-directories).

```
public static void removeDirectory(File dir) {
    if (dir.isDirectory()) {
        File[] files = dir.listFiles();
        if (files != null && files.length > 0) {
            for (File aFile : files) {
                removeDirectory(aFile);
            }
        }   
    }// else {
        dir.delete();
//    }
}
```

Comment: the recursive call to removeDirectory(aFile); was correct

Comment: Noticed that. Fixed it.

Comment: removing the slash is a bad idea... now it doesn't even delete the ZIP archive...

Answer (score 1):

I want to post this in a comment but I don't have enough reputation. I tried your method to delete files and it is ok but if you can delete the "output.txt" file should be because there is an object using the file it seems that you close all the streams but checking the code I saw that you use a Scanner object to get the appName maybe that could be the problem because the Scanner object is pointing to your "output.txt" file.

Change this:

```
String appName = new Scanner(new File("output.txt")).useDelimiter("\\Z").next();
```

for something like this:

```
Scanner scanObject = new Scanner(new File("output.txt"));
String appName = scanObject.useDelimiter("\\Z").next();
scanObject.close();
```

I'm not sure about new Scanner(new File("output.txt")); I think the scanObject.close() should close also the File object that you are passing to the Scanner object if not, try to separate that also and close the File object after use the scanner.

Comment: this helped with the `output.txt` file, but the XSLT generated files are still there...

Comment: I saw your last update, I think it should work, I don't see any stream that is not closed, so maybe saxon has a bug, check this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17998881/saxon-xslt-transformation-how-to-close-outputstream-when-failing-during-transfo maybe you could try another version

Answer (score 0):

1) reformat your code ... can't see anything

2) close your streams within a finally block

```
try {
    ...
} catch (Exception e) {
    ... handle your exception
} finally {
    close what you have to close!
}
```

3) " I tried to close all the streams, because I've read that not closed streams prevent deletion."
Well, I guess you have still open file handles. Even foreign file handles can prevent the deletion. Is any anti virus program scanning the files? Search the internet for tools to detect open file handles.

4) You can also test if aFile.deleteOnExit() works. "deleteOnExit" tries to delete the file on JVM shutdown.

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

If you're on linux you can do some command line versions of deleting files instead.

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("rm -rf");
```

'r' flag means recursion, meaning just start at the base and this command removes the directory and all subdirectories.

'f' flag forces it, doesn't ask you "do you want to delete xxxx.txt?" for every file.

you can also do something like

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("rm -rf *.java");
```

if you're only deleting Java files. Also, windows and mac have a shell delete file/ delete directory command. Hope this helps